# Consuming canvas graphiql using CURL in php where cant use url_fopen

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi all I'm Struggling trying to connect to the canvas graphiql (https://xxx.instructure.com/graphiql) using CURL as I have to use curl. I cannot get "allow_url_fopen" opened so I have to use CURL. details https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.graphql.html

could some one check if I am doing below in PHP correctly

```
<?php
$endpoint = "https://xxx.instructure.com/graphiql";//this is provided by graphcms
$authToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";//this is provided by graphcms
$qry = "query {allCourses {name assignmentsConnection { nodes {name dueAt } } }}";

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken;

$ch = curl_init();




curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);




$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

$decoded = json_decode($result,TRUE);


echo $decoded;


?>
```

Comment: your data are not JSON so `Content-Type: application/json` this is wrong, just leave it and curl will set it for you, your query is wrong, you are missing the field in there should be like: `$qry = "query='query {...}'";` and finally you are missing the `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: Thanks for the help... I managed to get it going with your help...removed the content type .... the apostrophe was causing me problems in the $qry... really really apricated.